# Go: Efficiently storing hex values in memory

Tags: go, hex, storage

I have two 16-byte hex values that relate to each other that I want to keep in memory in Go (so they only need to exist for the lifetime of the running process) that can be represented as a simple map like so:

`{"aabbcc": "112233"}`

Obviously I could represent these as a struct of two strings, but I'm just wondering if there's a faster (i.e. performance) or more memory-efficient way to store the strings in Go? I've only delved into Go lightly so far, so don't know the standard library well enough to know a good answer.

**Edit:** For an idea of what I'm getting at (in pseudo-code):

I've got two UUIDs from different sources, that are generated/received as strings:

```
uuid_a_1 = "aabb-1122-3344"
uuid_a_2 = "ddee-5566-7788"
```

I want to store these in relation to each other:

```
uuid_map[] = {uuid_a_1: uuid_a_2}
```

So that I can return one when I lookup the other:

```
return uuid_map[uuid_a_1]
```

I'm just curious if there's a more efficient way to store these in memory than a simple map of strings, as I may for example want to store several thousand during the lifetime of the process, and want to be able to key/value store these as quickly as possible (the idea being that because I know the exact size and type of the keys and values that I can do it fast).

Comment: At a guess, you can represent each number as a pair of `uint64`s.

Comment: Maybe show us how you want to access them or use them.

Comment: You could use a [16]byte, a 16-byte long array of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FUZxxl is suggesting you can encode the string to a byte array.

http://play.golang.org/p/7MYWTWSu2-

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    b, err := hex.DecodeString(strings.Replace("df31a780-f640-11e3-a3ac-0800200c9a66", "-", "", -1))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Decoded:", b)  
    fmt.Println("Encoded:", hex.EncodeToString(b))
}
```